# Why does the author advise against using random.seed in Hands on machine learning book?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I've been reading Hands on machine learning with scikit-learn, keras, ... by Aurélien Géron (2nd edition) and on pages 54-55 he discusses the steps to creating a test set.

He uses numpy's random.permutation method, but says that this has an issue i. e. everytime we run this program it will create a different test set and eventually our algorithm will see the entire set which isn't good so he says to either generate the dataset once and load it everytime after that or just use numpy's random.seed to get the same instance everytime.

This is the code for the numpy method:

```
import numpy as np
def split_train_test(data, test_ratio):
    shuffled_indices = np.random.permutation(len(data))
    test_set_size = int(len(data) * test_ratio)
    test_indices = shuffled_indices[:test_set_size]
    train_indices = shuffled_indices[test_set_size:]
    return data.iloc[train_indices], data.iloc[test_indices]
```

Further he says that "But both these solutions will break next time you fetch an updated dataset", now I understand that will be the case with the save once and load method. But I don't understand why that would be the case with the numpy method, as it is creating the test set from the input data set, so if we provide it the updated data set everytime, any changes in the original data set should persist right?

And I've also read an article as to why it's bad to use the numpy.random's global seed and instead we should use a generator instance's method which makes sense.

But I'm still struggling to understand the author's reasoning as to why both methods would break and why he has gone onto create test set using hashing and stuff

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's a machine learning question, and it belongs on Cross Validated or Data Science SE's.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it makes sense, that the algorithm won't get a glimpse of *all* the data, otherwise a test split would be obsolete, as you well understood.

So all these arguments address the case, that the program is run more than once. This could happen, for example, if the user will re-run the training, or further trains a pre-trained network. If such thing happens we need to make sure that the test-split remains hidden. The test data is used to compare different models, so if two models are evaluated on different test data, they cannot be compared in proper way. Please also note that people usually make a difference between train, test AND validation data...

Therefore, it is a bad idea to make a random split every time.

Alternatively he suggests to make a "deterministic" random split by using a seed. Setting the seed to the same value every time the program start, it will create the same sequence of random numbers, which is good. However, if the order of the data changes, for example, the file names change or are unordered in the first place, a deterministic sequence of "random" numbers won't address the issue anymore.

He then suggests that a test split could be saved separately to disc to prevent splitting the data more than once. This is a good work-around for the random-number issue.

However, when new data is available that has a new species, a new split needs to be created that also contains, say birds. If the pre-trained dog-cat network is now fine-tuned it is not guaranteed that a new naive split will leak old training data to the new test data set and therefore make you believe your model is better than it actual is.

I think the author wants to warn the reader, that these things happen easier than you expect and wants the reader to think about what will or can happen when a network is fine-tuned on new data or when updating training and test data. When you are aware of this you will always find a way to merge new data without causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> "But both these solutions will break next time you fetch **an updated
> dataset**"

The key part of the quoted text is highlighted. An updated dataset is not the same as the original dataset.

If you have set the same random seed then `np.random.permutation()` should return the same permutation of numbers, however the data is not the same so you are not going to get the same train/test split. You could use different datasets each with an identical number of rows, and they will be split on the same indices.

A hash function generates a number for a given input. Instead of using the number of rows in the dataset, the function can generate a value which could be used as an index to identify each row of the dataset. You could then use the index to perform the train/test split.

You choose the point in the index at which to split the data and so long as you keep this the same then the data will be consistent.

This gives you the certainty that if you update the dataset, then using a hash function will ensure that the original data will still have the same hash value and so won't move between the training and testing set. Any new data will be added to the training or testing set depending on the generated hash value.

You may need to perform an additional piece of work if the dataset does not contain a unique identifier for use in the hash function.